# silverlight enabled wcf service cannot return list

Tags: c#, sql-server, silverlight, wcf

hello guys i built wcf service i have two methods insert and get(which must return list) inserts method works correctly

This is get method:

```
 public List<string> GetUsersList() 
        {
            csmasterDataContext db = new csmasterDataContext();
            List<string> _uList = new List<string>();
            _uList = (from d in db.users select d.username).ToList();
            return _uList;
        }
```

when i call this method like this :

```
 List<string> _UserList = new List<string>();

            _UserList = webService.GetUsersListAsync();
```

visual studio gives error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'
```

Does anyone have a idea what is my problem?

Comment: did you checked my GetUsersList method? its returns _uList;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Async call of web service is asynchronous it does not return a value... you have to call it like this

```
webService.GetUsersListAsyncCompleted += 
      new EventHandler<GetUsersListEventArgs> (GetUsersListCompleted);

webService.GetUsersListAsync();

void GetUsersListCompleted(object sender, GetUsersListEventArgs e)
{
    // Set your return here
    usersList = e.Result;
}
```

check [this](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2009/06/22/consuming-wcf-services-in-silverlight-3.aspx) and [this](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=228)